# laravel broadcast on private channel not work with laravel-echo and laravel-websockets

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, pusher, laravel-echo

I am using `beyondcode/laravel-websockets` package in my backend, and `laravel-echo` & `pusher-js` in frontend.

I want to send a private message to the user by websockets from my own server.

**Backend**

`routes/channel.php`

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
use App\Models\User;

Broadcast::channel('users.{id}', function (User $user, Int $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

`app/Events/NewPrivateMessage.php`

```php
...
class NewPrivateMessage implements ShouldBroadcast{

    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(Message $message){
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public $message;

    public function broadcastOn(){
        return new PrivateChannel('users.'.$this->message->user_id);
    }

    public function broadcastWith(){
        return ['message' => $this->message];
    }
}
```

`config/broadcasting.php`

```php
...
    'connections' => [
        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http'
            ],
        ],
        ...
    ],
```

**Frontend**

```js
...
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.SPY = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    auth: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `${store.state.auth.token.token_type} ${store.state.auth.token.access_token}`
        }
    }
});

window.SPY.private(`users.${store.state.auth.user.id}`)
    .listen('NewPrivateMessage', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

---

But when I run code below in tinker, nothing happend, no logs, no `console.log()`

```php
broadcast(new \App\Events\NewPrivateMessage(\App\Models\Message::first()));
```

I am sure I remove comments in `config/app.php` for `BroadcastServiceProvider`

```
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

and the auth for broadcasting is successful

[image: the auth for broadcasting is successful]

also, I am sure I already connected with websockets
[image]

How can I fix this? I am using laravel 7.0. Thanks a lot ☺

Comment: Did you solve this? Looks like it's the same code I've got here.

Comment: @Tomas use `ShouldBroadcastNow` instead of `ShouldBroadcast` works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66343878/10519069