# Laravel broadcast events to Nuxt JS not being received

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, nuxtjs

I've got a Laravel 8.x project set up as an API with JWT auth. I'm using the [Laravel Websockets](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction) package, I've also got the [Laravel Echo package for Nuxt JS](https://github.com/nuxt-community/laravel-echo) installed along with Pusher JS and Socket.io

I've started my web sockets server, and it's running on port `6001` on `127.0.0.1`, but when I load up my Nuxt JS front-end, I don't see any events coming through?

My event is called `AgentStats`, and looks like...

```php
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\ProfilerAgent;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class AgentStats implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Profiler Agent Details
     *
     * @var \App\Models\ProfilerAgent
     */
    public $agent;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(ProfilerAgent $agent)
    {
        $this->agent = $agent;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('agents');
    }
}
```

My event is triggered via my controller which requires a user to be logged in, it's then triggered via:

```php
// $agent is my data
broadcast(new AgentStats($agent));
```

I've updated my `channels.php` file to include the new broadcast channel...

```php
Broadcast::channel('agents', function ($agent) {
    return $agent;
});
```

For my front-end, my Nuxt JS client, I'm a logged in user and am listening on my `agents` channel for my `AgentStats` event:

```js
<script>
export default {
  layout: 'account',
  mounted() {
    // nothing is logged
    this.$echo.channel('agents')
      .listen('AgentStats', (e) => {
          console.log(e)
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

My config is:

```js
buildModules: [
  // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-tailwindcss
  '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  '@nuxtjs/moment',
  ['@nuxtjs/laravel-echo',{
      broadcaster: 'pusher',
      key: 'websocketkey', // this is what's in my env
      encrypted: false,
      wsHost: '127.0.0.1', // default url
      wsPort: 6001,
      disableStats: true,
      authEndpoint: '127.0.0.1/broadcasting/auth'
  }]
]
```

Really not sure what I'm missing, I've been debugging for several hours and can't understand why my Nuxt JS project fails to show any data when I submit an event.

Answer (score 0):

In your AgentStats Event file use

```
    public function broadcastOn(){
        return new Channel('agents');
    }
```

instead of

```
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('agents');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `ShouldBroadcastNow` instead of `ShouldBroadcast`

before

```php
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class AgentStats implements ShouldBroadcast{...}
```

after

```php
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;

class AgentStats implements ShouldBroadcastNow{...}
```

here is a full example with websockets in SSR Nuxtjs with Laravel
https://github.com/DengSihan/bootstrap